# Best way to implement a common Interface for a custom class and a library class

Tags: c++, interface, polymorphism

I have a library class that I cannot change and a custom class. I want to use run time polymorphism on both but I cannot inherit from the library class since it is designed as a leaf class, nor from its far to general base class. What is the easiest and cleanest way to implement a common interface that serves as a "kind of base class" for both the library class and my custom class ? Is there a design pattern for something like this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [adapter pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern).

Comment: I should definitely spent some time with the GOF book. I have it here but ... :-P

Comment: @Martin once you're done with GOF, I recommend [modern c++ design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_C%2B%2B_Design) by Alexandrescu.

Comment: Not really. Patterns are just a guideline, and are often indicative of poor language design. You should think in terms of what makes good code, not what patterns can I use.

Comment: @Antimony I agree, but it helps to know a few of them, at least the general principles.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to wrap the library class in a wrapper class. Then create a common interface for the wrapper class and your custom class.

Alternatively if the types are known statically, you can just use template duck typing.

Comment: O dear, I feared sth. like that

Comment: @Martin if it in only one class then it shouldn't be too complicated to implement.